# Check if item is in array in Mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb

```
{
data: [9, 3, 56, 3, 54]
}
{
data: [6, 3, 5, 3, 5]
}    
{

    data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    }
```

How do I get the only object which has `1` in the `data array` in MongoDB?

```
db.findOne({"data":1 in data})
```

Is that it?

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
db.collection.findOne({"data":1})
```

This matches all documents where `1` is in the array. See [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#match-an-array-element).

Note that you (obviously) need to specify the collection.

BTW, this is pure Mongo shell, not pymongo. In pymongo, you'd write

```
db.collection.find_one({"data":1})
```